# sqlite create table column default value not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to execute an sqlite query which returns rows where a certain column has (null) value.  I tried many variations such as

```
SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId IS NULL
SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId ISNULL
```

These returned all rows, whether the BatchId was null or not.  The rows of interest show "(null)" in DbVisualizer column.  So then I thought maybe the column is really empty, so I tried

```
SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId = ''
SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId = ""
SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId = '""'
```

These resulted in no errors but no result set either.  Then I thought maybe it is literally '(null)' so I tried

```
SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId = '(null)'
```

This too resulted in an empty result set.  Then I thought maybe I will force the default value to be null so I created the table column like this:

```
BatchId DEFAULT NULL
```

That didn't work either.  The field still showed (null) and the queries behaved the same way. Then I thought, ok fine, I'll use 0 instead of NULL. So I created the field like

```
BatchId INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

You guessed it.  That didn't work either.  The column still showed (null).  Then I read somewhere that you also have to set the column to NOT NULL so I tried

```
BatchId INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

Now I get error

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL
>   constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   stack_contrib_tab.BatchId)

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I was successful at setting BatchId to 0, rather than null.  The error was happening later during an insert, not at table creation like I had thought.

Comment: There is no case that `SELECT ContribId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId IS NULL` will return rows where `BatchId` is not null. So you are doing something else. Execute this: `SELECT ContribId, BatchId FROM stack_contrib_tab WHERE BatchId IS NULL` and if you get rows where `BatchId` is not null then remove from your pc whatever db management software you are using.